# How to filter document libraries using CAML query?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, caml

In my powershell script, I get all lists, then loop through and filter based on if its a document library and if its a certain content type, but I want to do this through CAML.

This is the loop logic

```
# get all the lists from the source location
$sourceLists = $sourceWebObj.Lists;

# loop through all lists
foreach ($sourceList in $sourceLists) {

    # check if it's a valid document library and it's content type is what we want
    if($sourceList.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $sourceList.ContentTypes[$DocLibContentType] -ne $null) {

    }
}
```

How can I do the same thing with CAML?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CAML query is used to get information from List.

You requirement is to filter `Lists` which belongs to object `Web`. We can't use CAML for that.

I would suggest you use PowerShell piping etc.

Comment: But in this link, they do something like that
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75521/spsitedataquery-for-documents-using-caml-query

They access the BaseType like I do, which filters the lists.